# Can't exclude elements for sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enable sorting for container element but not to all childs elements. I tried to use `items` option but it still can drag when I click on child elements

```
$('.faqs-container').sortable({items: '.faq-container'});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="faqs-container ui-sortable"><div class="faq-container sortable" style="position: relative; z-index: 888888; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
                <a class="js-remove-faq-row remove-faq-row" href="#">Remove [x]</a>
                <lable>FAQ Title</lable><input type="text" value="lkjlkjklj" name="field_id_19[Uovprcx5cmLZIkyf][data][faqtitle][]"><lable>FAQ Body</lable>
                <div class="editor">
                    <div class="redactor_box"><div contenteditable="true" class="redactor_redactor_editor redactor_editor" dir="ltr" style="min-height: 200px;"><p>lkjlkjlkjklj</p></div><textarea data-config_key="d82b1dbcc543a2dfd246eecbea54bb88" class="redactor_editor" name="field_id_19[Uovprcx5cmLZIkyf][data][faqbody][0]" dir="ltr" style="display: none;">&lt;p&gt;lkjlkjlkjklj&lt;/p&gt;</textarea></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu6yrb0o/)

Comment: Please include your mark up.

Comment: @PeterRasmussen added to comment. You may also check it on fiddle

Comment: I don't understand why 2 person asked to close this topic, whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option 'handle', Restricts sort start click to the specified element.